# Why do Bubble, Insertion, and Selection sorting have the same Big-O?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

As the title asks, why do insertion, bubble and selection sorting have the same big-o? In my algorithms class we've covered four algorithms the ones above and merge sorting, also why would one even use any of the above algorithms instead of merge sorting?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at with this question.  Are you wondering what these algorithms have in common that makes them all have the same complexity, or are you wondering why the complexity is not something else?

Comment: You're asking two different questions here  1) Why are bubble, insertion, and selection O(n^2) and 2) What are valid use cases for them?  Ask these as separate after researching on your own.  Voting to close as overly broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While they are different algorithms, they have the same asymptotic complexity because at some level, each algorithm makes two passes through a list of length n. The key is that Big-O is a worst case performance measurement. An insertion sort is, in the worst case, O(n^2), but in the best case, when the list is already sorted, it becomes O(n). Different sorting algorithms have different strengths that require analysis beyond big-o complexity.

That being said, you're almost always better off using an nlog(n) sort, and the primary function of things like bubble sort is probably to introduce people to the concept of sorting algorithms.

Comment: Actually, insertion/selection sort are actually useful in practice, to be used when sorting 'small' arrays as a base case for the the recursive O(logn) sorts, since they're actually faster once n gets small enough

Comment: When N can fit into local cache (when N is small) insertion sort can be used. A similar idea is used in TimSort which is n log n until N gets small then it switches n^2 algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Even though some sorting algorithms like bubble sort are very slow for a large number of items, they are very fast when you have only a small number of items, partially because they are so simple.  Bubble sort or insertion sort can also be useful when the items are already close to being in the correct position.  It is often that case that a good sorting algorithm will use one technique to get the items sorted on a course scale, and then another algorithm to do the fine-scale sorting.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the more common questions that get asked here.  Big-O notation is a way to measure the theoretical bounds of an algorithm, this is where you get things being constant time O(1) in the best case, even though that rarely happens, hence best case.  The reason why these three algorithms have the same big O is that they all attack the problem of sorting in the same way, having the same big-O does not mean that these algorithms are remotely equivalent in the way that they work, even though the process is similar.  From a purely academic stand point the reason why these are taught is so you are able to learn from history and not think that you are going to "shock the world" by coming up with bubble sort.  It is also used to show how what appears to be a simple concept, i.e. sorting, can prove to be far more complex than what a "naive" approach will produce.

Comment: Very well worded and put, thank you.